# Modal script open always the same modal on the page

Tags: javascript

I'm not so good on js

I'm trying to add a global script to open modals.

Here is my script

```
    class BulmaModal {
    constructor(selector) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(selector)
        this.close_data()
    }

    show() {
        this.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')
        this.on_show()
    }

    close() {
        this.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')
        this.on_close()
    }

    close_data() {
        var modalClose = this.elem.querySelectorAll("[data-bulma-modal='close'], .modal-background")
        var that = this
        modalClose.forEach(function(e) {
            e.addEventListener("click", function() {

                that.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')

                var event = new Event('modal:close')

                that.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
            })
        })
    }

    on_show() {
        var event = new Event('modal:show')

        this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    on_close() {
        var event = new Event('modal:close')

        this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    addEventListener(event, callback) {
        this.elem.addEventListener(event, callback)
    }
}


const Modal = () => {
    const initModal = () => {
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.modal').length > 0) {
                var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-modal"), i;

                for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
                    var target = (buttons[i].getAttribute('data-target'));
                    var mdl = new BulmaModal("#" + target)
                    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                        mdl.show()
                    })
                }
      }
    };
    const init = () => {
      initModal();
   };
   return {
     init,
   };
};

export default Modal;
```

The modal is firing, but every **time it opens the same modal**. Every modal has a button with the target

```
<button class="is-success button toggle-modal" data-target="edit-participant">
Modify User
</button>
```

And every modal has an id that corrispond to the data target attribute of the button, so in this case

```
<div class="modal" id="edit-participant">
</div>
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `initModal` should be triggering `mdl` object which is set last. You can try updating your `for` loop like below.

```
const initModal = () => {
if (document.querySelectorAll('.modal').length > 0) {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-modal"), i;

    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
            var mdl = new BulmaModal("#" + target)
            mdl.show()
        });
    }
}
```